# Receiving ajax posted object in django view

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

needless to say i'm a rookie ! so here is my js code which send a js object via ajax to a view

```
function test(){
    arr = {} ;
    $('#settings_tab').find('.someclass').each(function(index, element) {
       key = $(this).attr('id') ;
       value = $(this).val();
       arr[key] = value;
    });

    $.post("{%  url 'setting-update' %}", 
       {arr:arr, csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'}, 
       function(){
          alert('done!');
       }
    );
}
```

posted data in firebug looks like this

```
arr[adminName]  
arr[contactAddress] 
arr[contactEmail]   
arr[contactPhone]   
arr[perPage]    
arr[siteDisableMsg] 
arr[siteTitle]  
arr[uploadSize] 
csrfmiddlewaretoken  BFrb8snw8zime8UI8Vukl8FirsHvDDUk
```

heer is my django view.py

```
def update(request):
    if request.POST :
        print('-------------------------------------------------')
        print(request.POST)
        arr  = request.POST.getlist('arr', None)
        print(arr)
        if(arr is not None):
            for k,v in arr:
                print(k)

    return HttpResponse('done !')
```

but in this line

```
   arr  = request.POST.getlist('arr', None)
   print(arr)
```

keep getting `[]` ... how can i get `arr` from POST ?

btw in the console when i print POST i get something like this

```
   <QueryDict: { 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['BFrb8snw8zime8UI8Vukl8FirsHvDDUk'], 'arr[adminName]': [''],
 'arr[uploadSize]': [''],  'arr[adminName]': [''],  'arr[contactEmail]': [''], 'arr[siteTitle]': [''], 'arr[perPage]': ['']}>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things to take note of there, first of all, JQuery is flattening your data-structure. For each element in your dictionary (that is, your `arr` variable), it creates a element in the `QueryDict` with a unique key.

So,

```
var arr = {'one': 'data1', 'two': 'data2'};
```

becomes

```
<QueryDict: {'arr[one]': 'data1', 'arr[two]': 'data2'}>
```

Which is very much aligned with what you are seeing. However, in your case, it doesn't actually seem like you are populating the array with values. Both your firebug and `QueryDict` output insinuates yu have a empty dictionary. I would investigate what value is in the following line of your javascript

```
value = $(this).val();
```

Also, you are using `getlist()` wrong, it gives you a list associated to a key in QueryDict, it doesn't give you a dictionary as you are expecting it to.

What you wan't to explore is the following, first serialise your array with `JSON.stringify()` as follows:

```
$.post("{%  url 'setting-update' %}" , { 'arr': JSON.stringify(arr), csrfmiddlewaretoken :  '{{ csrf_token }}' });
```

and then convert it to a python dict in the view by

```
import json
yourdict = json.loads(request.POST.get('arr'))
```

Comment: thanx , i've left the inputs empty that's why there is no value set in array ... im a php developer , in php we can pass a js object(dictionary in oython) or array(list in python) in the post request and php would receive them as array (which works like both dictionary and list ) , i thought python would create a dictionarry called `arr` in the POST and put them there....

Comment: .... but apparently python doesn't respect javascript data structure , it'l breaks the js object `(arr)` into it's own dictionary along with other posted data and to keep the same data structure we have to change js object to json string .....  how much did i get it right ?

Comment: Python isn't touching your javascript object, this is flattened by JQuery before being sent to the backend. You can check the request headers, the form data being submitted by the $.post method contains individual key/value pairs, for each entry you had in your javascript object.

Comment: It's been jonkers since i touched PHP (im a Java developer by trade, that just enjoys a bit of python on the side), but it sounds like its being helpful and converting keys in the format 'arrayName[keyname]' into an associative array for you. So you dont have to worry about it yourself. You could quite easily mimic this behaviour in any-language^tm if you see fit :D

Answer (score 1):

you need to serialize your object to json string first:

```
$.post("{%  url 'setting-update' %}" , 
    { 
      arr: JSON.stringify(arr), // <-----------
      csrfmiddlewaretoken :  '{{ csrf_token }}' 
    }, 
    function(){alert('done!')}    
});
```

then in views.py

```
arr = request.POST.get('arr')
dict_ = json.loads(arr)
```